# Does word alignment matter for keys?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, indexing

I am not able to find any clear documentation on whether we need to consider word alignment for a key (whether it's a primary key, clustering key or plain old index).

With row compression, it can be set up so that we use up storage space efficiently but I'm more interested in the CPU performance from joining on say, 5-byte wide key compared to 8-byte wide key. Am I mistaken to think that if a key can't be 4 byte, then I might as well go for 8 byte because 5/6/7 bytes would just mean 3/2/1 bytes would be wasted?

Comment: what is "word alignment for a key"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't affect performance, just storage space.

Answer (score 0):

Wider keys can cause performance issues in joins. If your natural key is wide, then consider using a surrogate integer key and putting a unique index on the natural key.

Comment: Of course it follows that wider is slower but that's not really what I am asking. What I am asking is if the key is 5 bytes, would the performance be just the same as a 8 bytes key simply because we had to align the 5 bytes and wasting 3 bytes to fit on a 64-bit machine's registers.